# testing observable completion

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

so i have a service:

```
@injectable()
export class MyService {
    public go() : Observable { /* does not complete returned observable */ }
}
```

and i have a test for its method's observable completion:

```
it('should complete', inject([MyService], (s : MyService) => {
     s.go()
      .timeout(10, 'did not complete')
      .subscribe(
           undefined,
           // if observable failed on timeout, fail test
           e => e == 'did not complete' && fail(e)
       );
}));
```

though we expect the test to fail, it finishes successfully because the fail function is called after the test is already done.

usually we'd solve this with `jasmine`'s `done`, but assuming i want to use angular's `inject` function, how can this be accomplished?

Edit: using angular's `async` and `fakeAsync` did not do the trick either, as `Observable`'s `timeout` tries to set an interval, which isn't allowed in these zones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to use `done` explicitly, you could, but I don't know how to make it compatible with the `inject` method. What you could do though is handle the `inject` in a `beforeEach`, or you can just get the services from the test bed (which acts like an injector)

With `beforeEach`:

```
let service;

beforeEach(inject([MyService], (s : MyService) => {
    service = s;
}))

it('...', (done) => {
})
```

Getting services from the test bed:

```
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

let service;    
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
  })
  let injector = getTestBed();
  service = injector.get(MyService);
})

it('...', (done) => {
})
```

Comment: `async` didn't work, it throws about trying to create an interval (which is what `Observable.timeout ` does probably). did you succeed running it?

Comment: btw, i've ended up using the last solution you've mentioned, and it does work.

Comment: No I didn't try it. One thing you can try instead of `async` is [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/fakeAsync-function.html). You need to call `tick`. You can pass a millisecond delay to the `tick` method. Maybe that will work. Maybe `async` doesn't support intervals. I don't know, maybe `fakeAsync` won't work either, but you can try it

Comment: nope, tried that. similar issue with different error message. thanks anyway, remove the first part of the answer regarding `async` and i'll mark it as the answer.